# how to enter credentials in Eclipse Subclipse/subversion SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subclipse

I can connect to SVN repo, it's public so there is no problem.
SVN Repository Exploring perspective, i'm clicking 'Add SVN Repository', it show form with only one field: url.
But i want to commit and i can't:

```
    Authorization failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Authorization failed
```

Why Eclipse didn't asked me for credentials? it assumed that if it could connect to repo, it doesn't need credentials ?
How to enter login/pass to be able to commit?

Answer (score 3):

Subclipse does not store credentials.  It relies on Subversion to ask for credentials via a callback in its API to prompt you when needed.  All Subversion clients share the same credential cache, so most likely you have already provided your credentials for this server and they have been cached.

Note that credentials are for "Authentication" (authn).  Your error message is that "Authorization" failed (authz).  So this implied you authenticated successfully and tried to do something you are not authorized to do.  Such as committing to a repository for which you only have Read access.